# Combinations cause Duplicate Entry error on prestashop webservice

Tags: xml, api, web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to add a product with combination trough prestashop 1.7 web-service using xml. The product is added fine but when I try to add combination only the first one is successful the others are bounced back with the following error

```
<error>
<code><![CDATA[97]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[SQL Error] Duplicate entry '53-1' for key 'product_default'. From ObjectModelCore->add() Query was : INSERT INTO `pstk_product_attribute`...</message>
</error>
```

This is the xml I'm sending, it's parsed correctly and of course the product already exists and all the product_option_values are defined by previous calls.

```
'<combination>'+
            '<id_product xlink:href="https://myprestashop.com/api/products/'+id+'">'+id+'</id_product>'+
            '<quantity>'+stock+'</quantity>'+
            '<reference>'+reference+'</reference>'+
            '<wholesale_price>'+wholesale_price+'</wholesale_price>'+
            '<price>'+price+'</price>'+
            '<minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity>'+
            '<low_stock_alert>0</low_stock_alert>'+
            '<default_on>1</default_on>'+
            '<associations>'+
                '<product_option_values>'+
                    '<product_option_value xlink:href="https://myprestashop.it/api/product_option_values/'+color+'">'+
                        '<id>'+color+'</id>'+
                    '</product_option_value>'+
                    '<product_option_value xlink:href="https://myprestashop.com/api/product_option_values/'+size+'">'+
                        '<id>'+size+'</id>'+
                    '</product_option_value>'+
                '</product_option_values>'+
            '</associations>'+
'</combination>'
```

An identical xml block is builded for every variation and the resulting string is then surrounded by a prestashop tag. This work for every other calls I've encountered but not this one, noticeably I get the same error if I send the combinations with a separate call for each one.
Am I missing some setting on the father object? The documentation is very lacking on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the part of `<default_on>1</default_on>`, only one combination per product can be **default_on** at **1**.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.